# Неправильное сложение цифр всех input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Здраствуйте! У меня такое задание. На странице есть несколько form, в form несколько input, в input числа. Я должен с помощью вложенных циклов сложить все числа input на всей странице. Проблема в том, что если в первый input я записываю число больше 9, т.е. двухзначное, трехзначное и т.д. , сначала почему то сумма чисел удваивается, а только потом идет сложение.

Вот код:

```js
let sum = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < document.forms[i].elements.length; j++){
    for(let k = 0; k < document.forms[i].elements[j].value.length; k++){
        console.log(sum);
       sum += Number(document.forms[i].elements[j].value);
    }
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
</form>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
</form>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
  <input type="text" value = 1></input>
</form>
```

Если вопрос не понятен, скажите мне об этом, я попробую переформулировать. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Ответ уже дали, но скажу по другому поводу: `input` не имеет закрывающего тега.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужен внутренний цикл - `k` нигде не используется.

```js
function sumAll() {
  let sum = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll("form input[type='text']").forEach(el => {
    var v = +el.value;
    if (!isNaN(v))
      sum += v;
  });
  console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" value="11" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
</form>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
</form>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="1" />
</form>
<br/>
<button onclick="sumAll()">Summ All</button>
```